# Keyboard predictions when typing in Safari address bar (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

When typing something into the search / address bar in Safari or Firefox, the predictions and autocorrect are disabled. This means I don't get suggestions to complete the current word I'm typing either.

Is there a way to enable this functionality? It does seem to work in a lot of places e.g. iMessage, but also realised it doesn't work in the app store search bar.

I've just moved over from Android, so apologies if this has an obvious answer.

Phone is running iOS 14.4.2

Comment: Please include the iOS version as Apple often makes changes when introducing a new OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though grg's answer says why this happens, it does not fix the problem.

My workaround has been switching to use SwiftKey instead of the default keyboard, this enables predictions seemingly everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The QuickType predictions don’t show when the text field has autocomplete disabled.

This is most often seen in inputs where completions appear as part of the text entry in the app. For example, regular QuickType predictions don’t appear in the Safari address bar because Safari shows autocomplete suggestions from your selected search engine. This is the same for App Store search, Spotlight, and others.